# How can a UIView subclass get notified when it has been added as subview to another view?

Tags: ios

I need some kind of hook or template method to override which gets called when a view is added as subview to another view, but couldn't find it in the documentation. It must be something that gets called automatically by UIKit. The reason is that my view must start some animations as soon as there is a superview, but stop animating as soon as there is no superview anymore.

I can't override -setSuperview: as Xcode is not indicating that such class exists - and I can't call super.

Answer (score 14):

You want to override [`- (void)didMoveToSuperview`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

> `didMoveToSuperview`
>
> **Tells the view that its superview changed.**
>
> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses can override it to perform
>   additional actions whenever the superview changes.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is also called when the view is removed from its parent, not just when it is added to a new parent. Code accordingly.

Comment: Editing answer to handle remove/add to superview.